# Is it good to pass attributes to angular custom button directive from like width, height, color, etc?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-directive

I am writing custom angular directive for the first time. Hence need to know whether is it the best practice to write as I have explained below.

I need to create a custom button which will be used throughout the app. I do not want to write the html button on each webpage and hence want to build a directive for it so that I can re-use it using a single line declaration.

My button has 3 states:

- invalid (initial)
- valid(when the form values satisfy the constraints) and
- hover state.

The button should have a static width, height, color, etc... But I also want to pass from the html in case if i want to have a special case in one of the forms, for example: I want to change the width only at one particular form.

I saw that we can pass the attributes from the controller but is it a good way to code?

Sample jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/y85Ft/7/

```
enter code here

<html>

</html>
```

Parameters key, value and accept are passed from the controller. Should I pass width, height, color, etc as well? Is it a good practice?

Kindly let me know the correct way.

Comment: You should paste actual code into the question and not just work around the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` on your `div` or `button` tags, `ng-class` can take some options that maps to your style.

you can check this [The Many Ways To Use ngClass](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

If you have some logic that is done by this `div` and is used in multiple pages that have different logic and you need to pass some options. I suggest you use Custom Directive for this

Answer (score 0):

Pass properties `<myButton isValid=... hover=... styles=... />`, where isValid is a flag: true or false, hover is a function within your controller and styles is a object containing your styles, like `{ color: ..., background: ... }`.